# Calling method from another class to use in switch statement

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a method from my `UserController` class to my `MainController`. However i can't seem to instantiate my method and therefore calling it has proved quite difficult.

Also the method I'm calling is to be used in a switch statement. Does this affect how i should go about it at all?

The `createUser` method. The method works code wise (tried having it in `MainController`) i just don't know how to instantiate it without doing it
through a switch statement.

```
  public static void createUser(){


   String username, password, repeatPassword, height, weight, address, email;

               int age, choice;
               double fitnessIndex; 

               String [] rank = {"Guld", "Platinum", "Diamond"};
               String [] sex = {"Mand","Kvinde"};

                System.out.println("Udfyld følgende for at blive oprettet som bruger: \n ");

                System.out.print("Navn:\n");
                username = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("E-mail:  ");
                email = input.next();


                // Regular expression som presierer hva emailen skal inneholde for å være valid

                while (!email.matches("([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\.\\.]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})")) {
                    System.out.print("Ugyldig Email, prøv igjen\n");
                    email = input.next(); }


                System.out.println("Alder:  ");
                age = input.nextInt();



                // Brugeren velger mellom 2 predefinerte koen
                do {
                    System.out.println("Vælg dit koen: ");
                    data.printArray1(sex);
                    choice = input.nextInt();
                } while (choice < 1 || choice > sex.length);



                System.out.println("Hoejde:   ");
                height = input.next();

                System.out.println("Vaegt:  ");
                weight = input.next();

                System.out.println("Adresse:   ");
                address = input.next();

                System.out.println("Kondital:  ");
                fitnessIndex = input.nextDouble();



                // Brugeren velger mellom 3 predefinerte muligheter for medlemsskab

                do {
                    System.out.println("Vælg ranken som passer deg bæst: ");
                    data.printArray(rank);
                    choice = input.nextInt();
                } while (choice < 1 || choice > rank.length);


                //beder brugeren om at vælge og gentage sitt kodeord


                do {
                    System.out.println("Kodeord:  ");
                    password = input.next();

                    System.out.println("Gentag kodeord  ");
                    repeatPassword = input.next();

                    if (!password.equals(repeatPassword)) {
                        System.out.println("Kodeordet er forkert, prøv igen!");
                    }
                } while (!password.equals(repeatPassword));

                User Unapproved = new User(username, password, 1, age, sex[choice-1], height, weight, fitnessIndex, address, email, rank[choice-1]);
                data.getUnapproveds().add(Unapproved);

                System.out.println("\nDu er nu blivet oprettet som medlem og venter på godkenning ");
                System.out.println("Så snart du er godkent vil du kunne logge inn, Velkommen til Motion CBS!️\n");

        }
```

Switch statement and me trying to call the method in `MainController`

```
            do try {
            choice = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            switch(choice) {
                case 1:
                    login();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    createUser(); // opret medlemskab
                    break;

                case 3:
                    login();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    onExit();
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Ugyldigt valg! Prøv igen");
                    break;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException eObject) {
            System.out.println("\n Du har indtastet en forkert variabel og bliver nu returnert til stratsiden");
            input.nextLine();
        printStartMenu();
    }

    while (currentUser != null);
}

{
   UserController userController = new UserController();
   userController.createUser();  }
```

So to clarify once again. The method won't be called, since i don't know how to instantiate the method in `UserController` first. So the CreateUser at the very bottom is RED (not working)

Therefore point 2 in the switch statement doesn't work. Any help and tips are appreciated as i want to understand what i'm missing and why

**EDIT**   I understand now that i haven't provided nearly enough information so i'll supplement under here

**UserController extends MainController**

```
 public class UserController extends MainController {

/**
 * The class constructor. Initializes the class and
 * its super class with instanses of the {@link MainController#data}
 * and {@link MainController#currentUser} objects.
 *
 * @param data        The instantiated data object.
 * @param currentUser The instantiated currentUser object.
 */
public UserController(Data data, User currentUser) {
    super(data, currentUser);
}
```

**Maincontroller**

```
protected Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

/** An instance of the Data class that holds all of the program data */
protected Data data;

/**
 *  The user currently logged in to the program.
 *  Defaults to null if no user is logged in.
 */
protected User currentUser;

/**
 * Default constructor for the Main Controller.<br>
 * Should <b>ONLY</b> be called from the Main Class, and only once.
 */

public MainController() {
    this.data = new Data();
}

/**
 * Constructor for instantiating when the Main Controller,
 * is the parent of a child controller.
 *
 * @param data          A reference to the instantiated Data object.
 * @param currentUser   A reference to the instantiated User object.
 */
public MainController(Data data, User currentUser) {
    this.data = data;
    this.currentUser = currentUser;
}
```

Comment: try `UserController.createUser();`

Comment: Since it is static you don't need to instantiate new. It can directly call like `UserController.createUser();` Also how do you execute your code. Is there a main method or test or server?

Comment: So i gave it a shot, but it still won't run.

Maybe i was unclear, or maybe you answered exactly what i was wondering. See the "CreateUser" in UserController is "Grey" (aka not running i guess) i'm guessing that is the problem. But i'm unsure as to how to

The code is executed through a main method

Comment: instantiating method? I don't know where that concept came from. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315657/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-instantiate-in-java

Comment: You talk about red and grey, what IDE are you using? Does the `createUser` method really compile, you are for instance referencing a variable `data` that I can't see being defined anywhere or is it static too?

Comment: That is my bad, extended information is provided in the original post now

Answer (score 0):

Since the `createUser` method is static, you can call it inside the Main controller using the Class in which the method resides, which in this case is `UserController`.

```
case 2:
       UserController.createUser(); 
       break;
```

Edit : The newly added code looks okay. Since I do not have the Data and User classes, I am assuming that there is anything wrong but at the same time I can give some points regarding the aspect of the code to clear any problems that you might be facing like with this one. You must be knowing most of the things, But just in case to clear any confusion you're facing:

> *I have absolutely no idea how to work around override and extends*

extends is a keyword used to inherit a class. In the current context `UserController` is a sub-class/child-class and the `MainController` is the super-class/parent-class. Inheritance is forming of a relation between class. You can use it to inherit the code that was already written in a class(MainController) and so you don't need to type the same thing inside the newly created class(UserController) which need the same properties.

Eg : My parent is a human being. I(child) am a human being. I inherited the qualities of a human being from my parent(and my parent inherited their qualities from their parents and so on).

It is important to note that constructors cannot be inherited, which is why in your code inside the `UserController` constructor you are using `super` keyword to invoke the `MainController`constructor and pass the values to it. Fields(except private fields) and methods(Except constructor) can be inherited.

> *I have absolutely no idea how to work around override and extends*

Overriding means that you are inheriting something from your parent, but you do not want it as it is and what to modify the implementation.

Eg : Suppose, you are inheriting a Jewellery shop from your parent. But you do not like it and so you chose to modify it in to a tea shop.

A small program would explain it better :

**Parent class**

```
public class parent {

public void wakeUp()
{
    System.out.println("I will wake up at 6am");
}

}
```

This is our parent class and it contains a method named wakeUp. Parent will wake up at 6am and so if this parent have a child then by default the parent will make the child also wake up at the same time(6am). In other words the child will inherit the qualities of the parent by default. You do not need to write any code inside the child class to get this quality(you just need to inherit the parent). It is like saying this is my parent and so I will get all the properties from my parent by default and here goes the code for that :

```
public class Child extends parent{


}
```

As we can see that we havent written anything inside the child class. But we have used the extends keyword which is declaring that the class named `Child` is the child of the class named `Parent`.

Now, overriding is when the child wants a different implementation. It is like saying I have different in views as compared to my parents when it comes to certain things.

Eg :

```
public class Child extends parent{

@Override
public void wakeUp()
{
    System.out.println("I will wake up at 10am");
}

}
```

Here, we are definiing the same method inside the child class. Wake up is the quality and this child doesn't like to wake up at 6am and so the child had overridden the quality(method) called wakeUp() and provided it's own implementation inside the body of the method. The child modified/overridden the quality that it got from the parent. But the parent's quality haven't changed. The parent will wake up at 6am and the child will wake up at 10am. I hope this helps you.

From this it is clear for us that we don't need to override a method if we want the same implementation/quality. So whatever is written inside the MainController is inherited by the UserController(with a few exception we have said earlier).

Comment: Alright so i think the reason it didn't work before was because of an override in the UserController class.

I'm trying doing it this way now. But i get the error message 

Non static method-'createUser()' cannot be referenced from a static context. However it is relying on user input so having it static won't work, right?

Comment: Since you have declared the method named createUser as static, you could call it using the class name like this : UserController.createUser();. That error message you are getting is because the method 'createUser()' is not static. But in the code you have provided it is static and so unless if you haven't modified the method declaration afterwards, there won't be an error. Now, even if it is not static we can do something to solve the issue...like using the object to call the method. Please provide more info if there are any modifications in code.

Comment: I posted an answer just now. I have absolutely no idea how to work around override and extends. I will edit the original post so you can look if you want

Comment: I have made some additions to my answer. i hope this helps you and if not feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seems to be struggling with inheritance and what you can and can't do from a superclass I would suggest that the best solution for now is to move the method `createUser` from `UserController` to `MainController` and removing `static` from the declaration and then simply delete the `UserController` class (of course move any other methods as well).

This will leave you with only one class and you can focus on getting your application to behave as you want. Introducing inheritance just for the sake of it is pointless and over engineering, once you have a running bug free version of your application then you could start considering re-factoring your code.