# Initialization of Main() in java and seeking alternative code

Tags: java, program-entry-point, java-10

I am given a following partial Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  var main = new Main();
  main.start();
}
```

I don't understand the initializing in Line 2 (Main()).

Also, what is the datatype of Main()? Suppose, I don't want to use 'var' keyword, then what should I use?

If there is any alternative code for this, please let me know.

Comment: Is that all the code you have?

Comment: use Main instead of var (old type)? You could debug as well if you want to know the type, you could print the type as well.

Comment: Do take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315657/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-instantiate-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005584/initialize-object-directly-in-java

Comment: `new Main()` is creating an instance of `Main` and calling its constructor `Main()` with no arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand the initializing in Line 2 (Main())

You're initializing an object of type `Main`, in order to call the instance method start()

The alternative is to replace `var` with `Main`

Or simply `new Main().start();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Main main = new Main();
   main.start();
}
```